# Nuget packages in VS17 showing warning sign and not downloading

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2017, dapper

I am trying to use Dapper with AspNetCore 2.0 web api. I have used this before but it is not working since I downloaded dotnet 2.1. It appears that the nuget package is not downloading. How do I determine the warning for this problem? If enough information below is available, what steps do I take to resolve this?

Simply nuget install dapper 1.50.5 (this also works for Serilog). And this displays:

[Dapper nuget warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DfQbO.png)

Assuming I had an error and the build was not working I removed reference to dapper and built.

[asp.net core build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpSXu.png)

But when I add a using reference I am getting an error:

[Dapper using error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0f4O.png)

I even changed the package management solution:

[nuget package management](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6QoH.png)

Comment: Try clearing Nuget Package Cache using Nuget Package Manager options and then try rebuilding the solution

Comment: This was the solution, once I cleared the cache everything worked correctly!

Comment: You have to clear Nuget cache to get it working or Update-Package -reinstall did the trick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to Reinstalling packages according to project target framework

```
Update-Package –reinstall <package_name>
```

> A package that is installed against an old target framework gets
>   uninstalled and the same package gets installed against the current
>   target framework of the project.

For more check **[When to Reinstall a Package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/reinstalling-and-updating-packages#when-to-reinstall-a-package)**

Or clear the nuget cache:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ezbT.png)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I deleted the folder `c:\Users\[youruser]\.nuget\packages` and nuget packeges where downloaded again once I rebuilded my solution.